# Delete list element from class

Tags: c++, list, erase

I try to delete list element and always get error message.

Firstly I have this class structure :

```
Class X
{ public:
  ID;
  name;
}
```

then I have list container.

Now, I want to delete specific element from container.

```
void delete ( list<X> a , X b )
{

list<X>::iterator itr;

for ( itr =a.begin() ; itr != a.end() ; itr++ )
{
    if ( *itr.ID == b.ID )
    { a.erase(itr) ; }
}
}
```

But, I get error:

> " iterator doesn't have ID ".

How can I fix it?

Comment: Once you've fixed that, you'll have to find a new name for the function, since `delete` is a keyword. `erase` and `remove` are common choices. You'll also want to pass `a` by reference, and remember the iterator invalidation rules. Or you could make life easier and use `a.remove(b);`

Comment: @MikeSeymour you mean pass `a` by reference

Comment: @bolov: Indeed I do. Corrected.

Comment: @MikeSeymour That would be `a.remove_if( [&]( X const& x ) { return x.ID == b.ID; } );`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @JamesKanze: You're right, I should probably refrain from making quick suggestions without compiling them first.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Your suggestion would work; it might not remove the same set of elements, however.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the dot operator `.` is "stronger" than the dereference operator `*`. According to [this table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), dot has a precedence of two, while dereference asterisk `*` has a precedence of three (lower is stronger). This means that without the parentheses the compiler tries to get iterator's member `ID`, and then dereference the value of `ID`. This is not possible, because the iterator has no member called `ID`.

You need to put parentheses to enforce the precedence that you want:

```
if ( (*itr).ID == b.ID )
```

Alternatively, you can use the `->` operator to dereference the iterator:

```
if ( itr->ID == b.ID )
```

Note: C++ Standard Library provides a way to do this without a loop:

```
a.erase(
    remove_if(
        a.begin()
    ,   a.end()
    ,   [](X x){ return x.ID == b.ID; }
    )
,   a.end()
);
```

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/1IlHj1)

Comment: /tmp/ccOJ9JuT.o: In function `delete(std::list<X, std::allocator<X> >, X)':
a.cpp:(.text+0x0): `delete(std::list<X, std::allocator<X> >, X)' multiple definition

now ,i get this error. However, i remove this function from my code, main run correctly.

Comment: @ort23 You need to rename your `delete` function, it is a reserved name.

Comment: @ort23 That is strange. Did you define your function in the header file?

Comment: @ort23 That's the problem then. You should declare it in the header (i.e. `void erase( list<X> a , X b );` or whatever is the new name of your `delete` function) and define it in the CPP file. Otherwise, there would be duplicate definitions for each time that you include the header in a CPP file.

Comment: He'll still have problems: erasing the element which an iterator points to invalidates the iterator, so his loop won't work.

Comment: @JamesKanze Agreed. However, OP needs to fix a compile problem at the moment (see comments above).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight He needs to fix both problems if he wants his code to work.

Answer (score 0):

i prefer to use itr->ID instead of *itr.ID. the later is a little confusing sometime.

Comment: Not just confusing; without parentheses, it's wrong, as the question says.