# What is a difference between *iterator.fun() and (*iterator).fun()

Tags: c++, iterator, dereference

I have simple code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;
class Example
{
    string name;
public:
    Example(string name)
    {
        this -> name = name;
    }
    string getName() const {return name;}
};
bool operator<(Example a, Example b)
{
    return a.getName() < b.getName();
}
int main()
{
    set<Example> exp;
    Example first("first");
    Example second("second");
    exp.insert(first);
    exp.insert(second);
    for(set<Example>::iterator itr = exp.begin(); itr != exp.end(); ++itr)
    {
        //cout<<*itr.getName(); - Not working
        cout<<(*itr).getName()<<endl;
    }

}
```

I wonder why `*itr.getName()` doesn't work but `(*itr).getName()` works fine. What is the difference between `*itr` and `(*itr)` in this case?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: Questions that asked something different than this one, but that have the same answer: [Vector push back operation with pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48014897/), [Delete list element from class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544797/), [How can I call a method of an object in a list iterator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74116507/), [Why can't I dereference a pointer to an object that's an array-element using the indirection operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030947/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ has rules for [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). According to these rules, the member access operator `.` has higher precedence than the dereference operator unary `*`.

Therefore, the expression

```cpp
*itr.getName()
```

Is interpreted as though it had the parentheses:

```cpp
*(itr.getName())
```

That is, it tries to evaluate `itr.getName()` and then dereference *that*. `itr` doesn't have any such member `getName`, so this doesn't compile. However, you can use the parentheses yourself to write:

```cpp
(*itr).getName()
```

This dereferences `itr` first, and then accesses the `getName` member of the resulting `Example`. You can also use the dereference-and-member-access operator `->` as follows:

```cpp
itr->getName() // Same meaning as (*itr).getName()
```

Comment: Glad I could help! If you feel this answers your question, please go ahead and hit the checkmark next to this answer to indicate that.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about operator precedence.

The `*` (pointer/indirection) operator has a lower precedence than the `.` (member access) operator, therefore when doing `*itr.getName()`, the compiler will first try to access `getName` as a property of `itr`, and then attempt to dereference the `value` returned by `getName()`, which becomes the value of the expression.

In short, your first attempt is equivalent to:

```
auto name = iter.getName();
return *name;
```

Your second attempt works because of the brackets because `(*itr)` will first derefernce the pointer, then `.getName()` will call `getName` on whatever the pointer was pointing to. This all works because of the bracket.

However, C++ also has another operator called the arrow operator (`->`), which allows us to directly access a member property of a pointee. Therefore, you could also use:

```
auto name = iter->getName();
```